# Adding Yii 1.1.x as dependency to yii based app, with composer?

Tags: php, yii, composer-php

While this path is ok for dev env:

1) PHP -> Composer -> Yii -> Yii app

When deploying I want to use:

2) PHP -> Composer -> Yii app requirements -> Downloading and Installing all the dependencies Yii included.

So:

**How to set up Yii framework as just dependency - second path (and not some franken monster that will be used to create empty app...)**

**Any clean Yii framework packages out there (that do not contain, demos, examplary apps, templates, docs, and any other things You DO NOT want on production?)**

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to say, that Yii 1.1.x is not natively compatible with composer.

Composer is neat piece of software, that is why Yii 2 has full support for composer and packages. Check it out, alpha version is already out there!

Comment: Need for production quality software :| But at least in the future it will be better.

Comment: If you are willing to develop project for couple months, Yii 2 is already good to go, if you are fluent in PHP and in Yii 1.